How to calculate the area of a quadrilateral given the (x,y) coordinates of its vertices
This problem is from the 2017 Gauss Contest (Grade 7).

Four vertices of a quadrilateral are located at (7,6), (−5,1), (−2,−3), and (10,2).
What is the area of the quadrilateral in square units?

I solved this by graphing the quadrilateral, then drawing a rectangle that encloses the quadrilateral and lastly computing the area of the quadrilateral by the calculation (the area of rectangle minus the total area of the 4 right-angled triangles outside the quadrilateral but inside the rectangle).  See my rough sketch below:

My answer of 63 agreed with the official solution.  What other ways are there to solve this problem?  I don’t care if they are simpler or more complicated than my solution.

In general you can't, because four points $A,B,C, D$ define three different quadrilaterals ($ABCD, ACDB, $ and $ADBC$) which will usually have different areas.

@MJD I guess we could just assume them in the given order?

I think your solution is the most straightforward one.

@Paŭlo Or if one of the three quadrilaterals is convex, as it is here, we assume that is the one that was meant.  But competition questions should be phrased more carefully.

@MJD Thanks for your insight!  I didn’t realize the contest question was ambiguous.

Two approaches for finding encloses area of a (simply connected) lattice polygon: apply Shoelace Theorem directly or graph accurately and apply Pick's Theorem, which involves counting.

Your solution was good; that is what I would have done, and I am a geezer 83 years old.  There is a general formula for the area of a triangle (formed with either diagonal of the parallelogram) when the three sides are known, but you are not likely to remember it (I don't).  But notice a few things about the problem:  The quadrilateral is actually a parallelogram.  The corner triangles in the enclosing rectangles are Pythagorean triples (3,4,5) and (5,12,13).  The problem creators wanted to make it easy for you.

@richard1941 The area of a triangle in terms of its sides can be found using Heron's formula.

You can make triangles surrounding the quadrilateral so that it forms a bigger rectangle. Then, you can possibly find the area of the rectangle, minus the area of the 4 triangles.

One rule that you will love after reading this is the Shoelace Theorem. It allows you to calculate the area of any polygon given that you know all the $(x, y)$ coordinates of the polygon's vertices.
Suppose you have an $n$ sided polygon bounded by the coordinates of its vertices:
$$\left(x_1, y_1\right), \left(x_2, y_2\right), \dots, \left(x_n, y_n\right)$$
then, the area $A$ of the polygon is given by the formula:
$$A = \frac{\left|\left(x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + \dots + x_{n-1}y_n + x_ny_1\right) - \left(y_1x_2 + y_2x_3 + \dots + y_{n-1}x_n + y_nx_1\right)\right|}{2}$$
I know the formula may seem a wee bit intimidating, but this isn't called the "Shoelace" Theorem for nothing. Yes, there's a trick to memorizing this formula! Simply create an $(n+2)\times 2$ table as shown below:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x & y \\ \hline
x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \\ x_3 & y_3 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ x_n & y_n \\ x_1 & y_1\\ \hline\end{array}$$
Now, "criss-cross" all $x_i$ with $y_{i+1}$ and then do the same for $y_i$ with $x_{i+1}$. Evaluate the difference of the two sums and finally, divide by $2$ to get your desired area.

God I love this one. I used it a lot in competition math in high school, and to circumvent some tedious calculations in my classes as well. Sucks that I never really had occasion to use it in college or beyond - aside from MSE itself.

This formula can be regarded as a specialization of Green's Theorem.

Here's a fun way:
Since the points are on a square lattice, use Pick's Theorem and count the integer points on the $b=\color{green}{boundary}$ and on the $i=\color{red}{interior}$
The area is given by a nice formula
$$A=\color{red}{i}+\frac{\color{green}{b}}{2}-1$$
Below is the example from wikipedia:

$i=\color{red}{7}$ interior points and $b=\color{green}{8}$ boundary points, so its area is $$A=\color{red}{7}+\frac{\color{green}{8}}{2}-1=10 \color{white}{:)} \text{square units.}$$

Damn nice! I too was planning to use Pick's theorem too in my answer

The quadrilateral is a parallelogram, so you can use the absolute value of the determinant:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}-5-(-2) && 1-(-3)\\10-(-2) && 2-(-3)\end{vmatrix}$$

This one popped into my head:
$(-5,1)$ and $(10,2)$ form a diagonal across this quadrilateral.  It is a parallelogram, but I am not using that here.
The equation of the line that forms this diagonal is $x-15y = -20$
The line parallel through $(-2,3)$ is $x-15y = 43$
The distance of this point from the diagonal is:
$\frac {|43- (-20)|}{\sqrt {15^2 + 1^2}}$
The area of the triangle with these 3 vertices is:
$\frac 12 \frac {|43- (-20)|}{\sqrt {15^2 + 1^2}}\sqrt{15^2 + 1^2} = \frac {63}{2}.$
The line parallel through $(7,6)$ is $x-15y = -83$
The area of the triangle above the diagonal is also $\frac {63}{2}.$
It isn't how I would recommend doing it, but it will work, and it is within the basic algebra curriculum.

HINT:
We can find equations of the diagonal, its length  and also lines perpendicular to it (slope negative reciprocal
passing through known point) containing altitudes $h1,h2$ with intersections $(P,Q)$.
$$ A= \frac12\cdot d \cdot (h1+h2) $$

Alternately the area of a triangle with three given points can be computed as per determinant of matrix:
$$ \frac12 \cdot 
\begin{vmatrix}x1 && y1 && 1 \\x2 && y2 && 1 \\ x3 && y3 && 1\end{vmatrix}$$
Two triangle areas one on either side of the diagonal can be computed and summed.

This solutions uses vector math and the cross product. Or if you're feeling fancy you could also use the wedge product from geometric algebra.
Label the vertices as follows:

Since the area is a parallelogram, the area is given by the length of cross product of the side vectors along its diagonals:$$\text{area}=||\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}\,||$$
The calculation is straightforward.
(7,6), (−5,1), (−2,−3), and (10,2).
\begin{align}
\vec{AB} = \pmatrix{10\\2}-\pmatrix{-2\\-3}=\pmatrix{12\\5}\\
\vec{AD} = \pmatrix{-5\\1}-\pmatrix{-2\\-3}=\pmatrix{-3\\4}
\end{align}
We now need to promote these vectors to 3D to be able to take the cross product.
\begin{align}\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}&=\pmatrix{12\\5\\0}\times \pmatrix{-3\\4\\0}\\
&=\pmatrix{0\\0\\12\cdot 4-(-3\cdot 4)}\\
&=\pmatrix{0\\0\\63}
\end{align}
And so the norm of this vector is 63, which is the area.
Equivalently, we can use the wedge product. The computation is identical but we don't need the third dimension. The wedge product has the property that $u\vee v=-v\wedge u$ and $u\wedge u=0$. It also distributes over its argumetns. We calculate the wedge product between $AB$ and $AD$ again:
\begin{align}
\vec{AB}\wedge \vec{AD}&=(12 e_1+5 e_2)\wedge (-3 e_1+4 e_2)\\
&=12\cdot(-3)\underbrace{e_1\wedge e_1}_0 + 12\cdot 4\, e_1\wedge e_2 + 5\cdot(-3)e_2\wedge e_1 + 5\cdot 4\, \underbrace{e_2\wedge e_2}_0\\
&=12\cdot 4\, e_1\wedge e_2 - 5\cdot(-3)e_1\wedge e_2\\
&=(12\cdot 4 + 5\cdot 3) e_1 \wedge e_2\\
&= 63\, e_1 \wedge e_2
\end{align}
